# Sharepoint Web part properties will not cover in Site Template?

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-template, cswp, web-part-property

Whether SiteTemplate will include all the CSWP web part Properties or not? I referred this link [Site Template](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/save-download-and-upload-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template#bkmk_additionalresources)

I am clear about uses and supports of the Site template, But I am not sure whether it will include the web part properties or not. Please suggest me some infromation about this

Comment: Bro, where you will use this site template , in the same farm ?

Comment: Yes bro. In same farm only

Comment: Do you try to save a test site as a template with SCWP and try it? Is CSWP web part Properties are not included or you faced a specific issue?

Comment: Ya I tried with test site and default cswp, Display templates are not updated. I mean if I choose one display template ex i choose picture only  and after creating the site using template default display template is only applied  not the selected one.

Comment: I don't now why it happened but in CQWP it's working , as a workaround try to export it from the site and import it back to the new site